# How to connect to sql database located locally in r shiny

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I am trying to connect to SQL database located in the same directory as in my app.R file but I get the following error if I try to connect.

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "super_data")
```

> Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
>     Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (0)

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='', dbname='super_data.sql', host='localhost')
```

> Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
>     Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (0)

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code:

```
conn <- RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                              user = "root",
                              password = "mypassword",
                              dbname = "mydatabase",
                              host = "127.0.0.1", # Instead of localhost
                              port = 3306) # Default MySQL port
```

Hope this can help

Comment: It is just a .sql file lying in the same directory do I need to host it somewhere before running this line?